# How to extract Url elements from list item in C# windows form app

Tags: c#, regex, list, url-rewriting, text-processing

Here is the concept my C# list items contains

```
List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();

Urls some are: 
http://www.google.com

http://www.google.com/maps

http://www.google.com/?parm=vlue

/www.google.com/
```

they are currently residing in a list variable myList1

Is there a way to identify each of the url elements like

```
Scheme:http

host:www.google.com

path:/maps

query:?parm=value
```

and set those elements as bool so if it is true do something if it is false do something else I don't even know where to start tried regex but not having any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

Sample code based on Arran's suggestion:

```
           List<string> myList1 = new List<string>() { "http://www.google.com/?parm=vlue"};

            var uris = myList1.Select(u => new Uri(u));

            foreach (var uri in uris)
            {

                //"http"
                var schema = uri.Scheme;

                //www.google.com
                var host = uri.Host;

                //"?parm=vlue"
                var query = uri.Query;
            }
```

Adding some more info. Could be useful

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(myURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

In your example:

```
IList<string> wellFormalteUriStrings = myList1.FindAll(url => Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute));
```

List **wellFormalteUriStrings**  would contain only the valid URL stings from **myList1**

Ref: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx)

Comment: I Really don't want to validate the list elements but just want to see if those elements exists

Comment: @zman: Updated my answer based on Arran's suggestion. Please check..
They are all string values. You could do a string.IsNullOrEmpty(host) to check if they exists.

Comment: Thanks it worked but I had to add system.web in the namespace and in the solution explorer reference and syste.collection.special... for urlparsing

Answer (score 2):

Make the list into `URI` instances:

```
var uris = myList1.Select(u => new Uri(u));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Which will then give you access to the various properties, such as Scheme and Host.

Say I have this in my list (among other things):

http://www.google.co.uk/search.php?searchterm=a

I could get this into a Uri first:

```
var uris = myList1.Select(u => new Uri(u));
```

Now I want only those that are going to `google.com` and have a `scheme` of `https`...

```
var googleUris = uris.Where(u => u.Host.Contains("google") && u.Scheme.Equals("http"));
```

So I've now only got URIs that are going to Google and accessing it over https, great, but it's also in a URI object now, so what if I just want it back as a full URI path?

```
var fullURIsOfGoogleUris = googleUris.Select(u => u.AbsoluteUri);
```

This final list would now be, just strings (the full URIs you gave it in the first place).

You mentioned you want it as a "bool" value...well you can use `Any()` for this. Using my above example this would turn into one line of:

```
bool hasGoogleUris = myList1.Select(u => new Uri(u)).Any(u => u.Host.Contains("google") && u.Scheme.Equals("http"));
```

The above would give you a `true` or `false` value depending on whether that list contained a URI that contained `google` in it's host and accessing it over `http`.

Comment: Would please give an example how would i check for one of those elements [note:I don't want to validate I just want to see if it is there if not do something if do something else]

Comment: @zman, what exactly are you attempting to achieve? Checking to see if they are URI's at all? Checking to see if any have a certain scheme or host? Checking if the URI contains a certain query string value? Checking any of the URIs have a certain protocol?

Comment: I am not trying to validate any of the input rather check to see if schme exists, host exists, quary exists and if any of those elements exists then format the individual list in certain ways and display them back with final formatted version

Comment: @zman, have expanded my answer. Please let me know if it doesn't help. Jacob's answer below will, or at least should, help too.